# Replace elements of a matrix with zeros using another matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

I have a matrix `Mat1` whos columns are ordered as :

```
Col = Flatten[Outer[{#2, #1} &, {0, 1}, Delete[Range[-2, 2, 1], 3]], 1]
```

and the rows are ordered as:

```
Rows = Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2} &, Delete[Range[-1, 1, 1], 2], Delete[Range[-1, 1, 1], 2]], 1]
```

The matrix is given as:

```
Mat1 = Outer[f[Flatten[{#1, #2}]] &, Col, Rows, 1]
```

> $$ \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  f(\{-2,0,-1,-1\}) & f(\{-2,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{-2,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{-2,0,1,1\}) \\f(\{-1,0,-1,-1\}) & f(\{-1,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{-1,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{-1,0,1,1\}) \\f(\{1,0,-1,-1\}) & f(\{1,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{1,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{1,0,1,1\}) \\f(\{2,0,-1,-1\}) & f(\{2,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{2,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{2,0,1,1\}) \\ f(\{-2,1,-1,-1\}) & f(\{-2,1,-1,1\}) & f(\{-2,1,1,-1\}) & f(\{-2,1,1,1\}) \\ f(\{-1,1,-1,-1\}) & f(\{-1,1,-1,1\}) & f(\{-1,1,1,-1\}) & f(\{-1,1,1,1\}) \\ f(\{1,1,-1,-1\}) & f(\{1,1,-1,1\}) & f(\{1,1,1,-1\}) & f(\{1,1,1,1\}) \\ f(\{2,1,-1,-1\}) & f(\{2,1,-1,1\}) & f(\{2,1,1,-1\}) & f(\{2,1,1,1\}) \end{array}
> \right)$$

Another matrix `Mat2` with a fewer elements is given as:

```
Mat2 = Outer[f[Flatten[{#1 , #2}]] &, {{-2, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}}, {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}, 1]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  f(\{-2,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{-2,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{-2,0,1,1\}) \\ f(\{1,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{1,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{1,0,1,1\}) \\ f(\{2,1,-1,1\}) & f(\{2,1,1,-1\}) & f(\{2,1,1,1\}) \end{array}
> \right)$$

I want to make all the elements of the first matrix (`Mat1`) equal to zero that are not same as elements of `Mat2`. This will create a kind of a sparse matrix like:

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc} 0 & f(\{-2,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{-2,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{-2,0,1,1\}) \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & f(\{1,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{1,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{1,0,1,1\}) \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & f(\{2,1,-1,1\}) & f(\{2,1,1,-1\}) & f(\{2,1,1,1\}) \end{array}
> \right)$$

How can I do this? (and for any general `Range` of `col` and `Rows`)

**Edit:**  Building `Mat1` with `Outer` for a large list of `Rows` and `Col` causes my system to hang and removes all variables from Mathematica. `Outer` carries out the arrangement of the elements at the positions I need in the matrix but it doesn't work for very big dimensions. I am only interested in the final sparse matrix with the elements at the positions dictated by the list of `Rows` and `Col`. Is there any way to get the final matrix by somehow using `Rows` and `Col` without the need to build `Mat1`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** An approach to use `Col`, `Rows` and the indices used to create `Mat2` to get the desired sparse array without creating `Mat1`:

```
c2 = {{-2, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}};
r2 = {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}};
positions = Tuples[{Flatten@Position[Col, #]& /@ c2, Flatten@Position[Rows, #]& /@ r2}];

SparseArray[positions -> Flatten @ Mat2, Length /@ {Col, Rows}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & f(\{-2,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{-2,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{-2,0,1,1\}) \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & f(\{1,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{1,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{1,0,1,1\}) \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & f(\{2,1,-1,1\}) & f(\{2,1,1,-1\}) & f(\{2,1,1,1\}) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

If you like, you can use `f` directly without having to use `Mat2`:

```
SparseArray[positions -> (f[Flatten[{Col[[#[[1]]]], Rows[[#[[2]]]]}]] & /@ 
     positions), Length /@ {Col, Rows}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> same result

**Original answer:**

#### [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html)

You can define a function `f0` that takes two matrices as input and returns a `SparseArray` with the desired entries:

```
ClearAll[f0]
f0[m1_, m2_] := Module[{pos = Position[m1, Alternatives @@ Flatten[m2]]},
   SparseArray[pos -> Extract[m1, pos], Dimensions[m1]]];

f0[Mat1, Mat2] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & f(\{-2,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{-2,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{-2,0,1,1\}) \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & f(\{1,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{1,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{1,0,1,1\}) \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & f(\{2,1,-1,1\}) & f(\{2,1,1,-1\}) & f(\{2,1,1,1\}) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

#### [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

Alternatively, define a function `f1` that gives `0` for any input except one that matches elements of `Mat2` and use it with `ReplaceAll`:

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1[x : Alternatives @@ Flatten[Mat2]] := x
f1[_] := 0;

Mat1 /. a_f :> f1[a] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> same result

You can also `Map` `f1` on `Mat1` at level 2:

```
Map[f1, Mat1, {2}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> same result

or use it to construct the result directly without creating `Mat`:

```
Outer[f1@f[Flatten[{#1, #2}]] &, Col, Rows, 1] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> same result

Comment: That is a very nice answer but my problem is in using `Mat1` when I have a large list of `Rows` and `Col`. When I run the code `Mat1 = Outer[f[Flatten[{#1, #2}]] &, Col, Rows, 1]` my Mathematica hangs and maybe runs out of memory. Is there any way to get the final matrix by somehow using `Rows` and `Col` without the need to build `Mat1`?. Outer carries out the arrangement of the elements at the positions I need but it doesn't work for big dimensions.

Comment: @jsid, please see the update.

Comment: Great. Seems to work really good for now. Let me test it further.

Comment: How time efficient will your method be for a matrix size of `16777216` by `1024`, Is there a way to know this?. I had been running your code for an hour now but its still going on.

Comment: @jsid, how big is `Mat2`?

Comment: `Mat2` is 62250 by 1024

Comment: @jsid,  with `dims = {dimr, dimc} = {16777216, 1024};
dimsmat2 = {dimm1r, dimm1c} = {62250 , 1024};
{rows, cols} = {RandomSample[Range[dimr], dimm1r], 
   RandomSample[Range[dimc], dimm1c]};
indices = Tuples[{rows, cols}];
mat2 = RandomInteger[100, {dimm1r, dimm1c}];`
it takes about `2.1261647` seconds for  `SparseArray[indices -> Flatten@mat2, dims] ` to give a result.

Comment: Sorry, I think I should have given the complete dimensions. So `Dimensions[Col] = {16777216, 4}`, `Dimensions[Rows] = {1024, 2}`, `Dimensions[col2] = {62464, 4}`,`Dimensions[row2] = {1024,2}`.

Comment: I have asked a new question concerned with the speed. Link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182294/increasing-the-speed-of-sparse-array

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
Col = Flatten[Outer[{#2, #1} &, {0, 1}, Delete[Range[-2, 2, 1], 3]], 1];
Rows = Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2} &, Delete[Range[-1, 1, 1], 2], Delete[Range[-1, 1, 1], 2]], 1];
```

and:

```
c = {{-2, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}};
r = {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}};

Mat2 = Outer[f[Flatten[{#1 , #2}]] &, c, r, 1];
```

You can construct your desired sparse array with:

```
sparse = Module[{m = SparseArray[{}, {Length[Col], Length[Rows]}]},
    m[[
        Flatten @ Position[Col, Alternatives @@ c, 1],
        Flatten @ Position[Rows, Alternatives @@ r, 1]
    ]] = Mat2;
    m
];
```

Check:

```
sparse //MatrixForm //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & f(\{-2,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{-2,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{-2,0,1,1\}) \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & f(\{1,0,-1,1\}) & f(\{1,0,1,-1\}) & f(\{1,0,1,1\}) \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & f(\{2,1,-1,1\}) & f(\{2,1,1,-1\}) & f(\{2,1,1,1\}) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: I would like to ask you the same question as how time efficient will your method be for a matrix size of `16777216` by `1024`?. I haven't yet run your code but would soon do.

Comment: @jsid Depends on the dimensions of Mat2. What are they? Or equivalently, what are the lengths of `c` and `r`?

Comment: Length of `c` is 62250 and `r` is 1024

Comment: @jsid Those dimensions should not be a problem. What is `f`?

Comment: `f` is a function that is needed to be evaluated after the matrix has been formed. Each evaluation of `f` takes on an average about `0.02` seconds with `Absolute Timing`.

Comment: Then it is `f` you need to speed up. `.02 * 62250 * 1024` is about 354 hours.

Comment: Sorry, the complete dimensions are `Dimensions[Col] = {16777216, 4}`, `Dimensions[Rows] = {1024, 2}`, `Dimensions[c] = {62464, 4}`, `Dimensions[r] = {1024,2}`. And, I did not define the function `f` yet, its just a variable before the matrix is computed.

Comment: @jsid Assuming `f` does become a function, I would try to speed up the creation of `Mat2` after defining `f` so that you can take advantage of vectorization. I expect that creating a matrix of `f` objects, and then defining `f` later will be agonizingly slow.

Answer (score 0):

The second matrix is more like a list of elements you want to set to zero.
Therefore I'd suggest

```
Mat2List = Flatten[Mat2]
Do[
If[MemberQ[Mat2List,Mat1[[j,i]]],
(*then we are good to go*),
Mat1[[j,i]] = 0
]
, {i, 1, Length[Rows]}, 
{j, 1, Length[Col]}
]
```

Which checks for all members of Mat1 whether they are in Mat2

Comment: Your code is working but when I increase the dimensions of the `Rows` and `Col` my Mathematica hangs and all the variables are removed. How can I use this for big matrices?. I only need the final matrix with the zeros and the elements of `Mat2` at correct positions in the matrix. I do not need `Mat1`, is there a way to create such sparse matrix?.