# Increasing the speed of sparse array

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, memory

I am trying to find a sparse matrix of the size `Col x Rows = 16777216 x 1024` where all the elements are `0` except the ones given by `col2` and `row2`. This is related to a previous question I asked: [Link to the question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182239/replace-elements-of-a-matrix-with-zeros-using-another-matrix)

The answer by [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) solved my problem for smaller size of the sparse matrix but when I use bigger sizes of `Rows, Col, col2, row2`, as in the code given below, the computation goes on forever with no way of knowing when this would complete.

```
Col = Flatten[Outer[{#4, #3, #2, #1} &, Range[0, 1023, 1], Range[0, 31, 1], {1}, DeleteCases[Range[256, -256, -1], 0, Infinity], 1], 3];

Rows = Flatten[Outer[{#1, #2} &, DeleteCases[Range[-16, 16, 1], 0, Infinity], DeleteCases[Range[-16, 16, 1], 0, Infinity], 1], 1];

col2 = Flatten[Outer[{#4, #3, #2, #1} &, RandomChoice[Range[0, 1023, 1], 64], RandomChoice[Range[0, 31, 1], 16], {1}, RandomChoice[DeleteCases[Range[256, -256, -1], 0, Infinity], 61], 1], 3];

row2 = Rows;

positions = Tuples[{Flatten@Position[Col, Alternatives @@ col2], 
                 Flatten@Position[Rows, Alternatives @@ row2]}];

SparseMat = SparseArray[positions -> (f[Flatten[{Col[[#[[1]]]], Rows[[#[[2]]]]}]] & /@ 
                        positions), Length /@ {Col, Rows}];
```

My question is how can I speed up this computation?. Is there a faster way to do this?.

Comment: Whould you share with us what `f` is?

Comment: `f` is a function but in this code it is just a variable. I thought of computing this matrix first and then define what `f` is, because every single computation of `f` takes about `0.02` seconds.

Comment: It is absolutely contraproductive to use symbolic code here. For example, the `SparseArray` cannot store the values in a packed array, if the values are not machine numbers. In the end, the values must be calculated anyways. So, please give me a concrete example for `f`.

Comment: Let it be for example `f[{a_, b_, c_, d_, i_, j_}] := a + b + c + d + i + j;` then?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses packed arrays throughout and replaces `Position` with the significantly faster `Nearest`. (`Position[Col, Alternatives @@ col2]` needs about `Length[Col] Length[col2]` operations; `Nearest[Col -> Automatic, col2, {1, 1}]` needs only `Log[Length[Col]] Length[col2]` operations. So that's $10^{12}$ vs. $10^{6}$ operations.)

Moreover, compiling the function `f` such that it is threaded and parallelized over its first argument speeds up the evaluation `f`.

Admittedly, there are much faster ways to do this for the `f` provided by OP. But this should also accelerate more general functions.

First the compiled function

```
cf = Compile[{{X, _Integer, 1}, {Y, _Integer, 2}},
   Table[
    Plus[
     Compile`GetElement[X, 1],
     Compile`GetElement[X, 2],
     Compile`GetElement[X, 3],
     Compile`GetElement[X, 4],
     Compile`GetElement[Y, i, 1],
     Compile`GetElement[Y, i, 2]
     ], {i, 1, Length[Y]}],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Now, the restructured code runs through in about 6 seconds:

```
n = 1024;
Col = Tuples[{
    Range[0, n - 1, 1],
    Range[0, 31, 1],
    {1},
    DeleteCases[Range[256, -256, -1], 0, 1]
    }][[All, {4, 3, 2, 1}]];
Rows = Tuples[DeleteCases[Range[-16, 16, 1], 0, 1], 2];
nf = Nearest[Col -> Automatic];


col2 = Tuples[{
    RandomChoice[Range[0, n - 1, 1], 64],
    RandomChoice[Range[0, 31, 1], 16],
    {1},
    RandomChoice[DeleteCases[Range[256, -256, -1], 0, 1], 61]
    }][[All, {4, 3, 2, 1}]];
p1 = Flatten[Flatten[nf[col2]]];
positions = Tuples[{p1, Range[Length[Rows]]}];
values = Flatten[cf[Col[[p1]], Rows]];
SparseMat = SparseArray[positions -> values, Length /@ {Col, Rows}, 0];
```

Comment: Since `col2` is randomly generated, the OP may wish to do this procedure multiple times with different randomly generated values for `col2`. In that case, it makes sense to define `nf = Nearest[Col -> Automatic]` once, and then use `Flatten @ nf[col2]` for each invocation of `col2`.

Comment: Your code is really fast in computing the `SparseMat `. But, after the computation my Mathematica slows down a little, maybe on a powerful computer with more RAM it wouldn't and operations on `SparseMat ` wouldn't hang. Btw, with `ByteCount`, `SparseMat` takes `1.07813 Gb` of space.

Comment: @jsid, my friend: It is not my fault that you want to assemble such a fat matrix. ^^

Comment: Ya, thanks that's a really fast code. But its is required to be a fat matrix since I need to carryout SVD on the complete matrix.